# Questions inappropriately closed are too hard to reopen

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, re-open

[What are the commonest checkmating moves in the Lichess (or similar) database?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/44959/what-are-the-commonest-and-rarest-checkmating-moves-in-the-lichess-or-similar) has been closed by 2 people.

How is it that 2 people are sufficient to close a question, while 5 are required to reopen it? We have 2 people who have voted to reopen it. Not to mention the 6 people who upvoted the question and 6 people who upvoted the answer (an excellent one by a relative newcomer). Counting the question and the answer itself, the total of 1+1+2+6+6=16 positive opinions expressed are insufficient to outweigh the 2 unexplained votes that closed this.

Also the reopen button only appears **after** the post has been closed. So the 5 people required to reopen can only begin to vote by coming back later.

Note also that there is no suggestion given by the two casual closers how it might be refocused. They merely click a button to invalidate all the hard work by questioner and answerer. In my opinion this is a naturally multi-faceted question, with a single scope (focus). It's really fine.

Stackexchange has, accurately in my opinion, a reputation for toxic behaviour, and I will continue to hold to account those who in my opinion are behaving badly.

So what to do?

Firstly, let this question be immediately re-opened, and kept open until 5+ people have voted for its closure.

Secondly, let's make sure that all questions can only be closed if 5+ people vote for it. If 5 people vote for closure, that is more likely to be an appropriate decision.

If these mechanisms don't work, then something more radical may be required. For example, re-open votes can directly count against close votes, and if the number drops to a low enough threshold, the question will be reopened automatically.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: I see that that, rather than engage here in Meta on the general principle and fixing the broader problem, one of the closers has chosen unilaterally to edit the question to reduce the scope, and apparently reopened it. No consultation with OP, no explanation and no apology.

I'm glad the question has been reopened, although in my opinion, the original scope (essentially examining extreme frequencies of final moves) was fine, as it requires the same kind of analysis.

The broader question remains: how to correct (or avoid altogether) inappropriate closures by very small numbers of votes?

Comment: As the author of the closed question, yeah, it's a bit frustrating. Especially with no explanation - did the voters object to me asking about both most common and rarest moves? The alternative would be to have separate questions, but considering that the bulk of the work in answering would be the same in both cases, it just seems a bit annoying to do so.

Comment: I am very glad to see this question reopened.  Will post an answer when I get time. I hope to see @SteveBennett  ask the other question too.

Comment: @secretagentman If you felt that this should be split into two questions, then you could have simply made a comment to this effect. I believe you were one of the two persons who together unilaterally closed this question. That’s really not very constructive behaviour. If you were unhappy about the response to your comment, you always had voting for closure available as a later sanction

Answer (score 4):

Questions are closed when they get 5 "ordinary" close votes or 1 moderator. Reopening uses the same standard. As it happens, both the close and the reopen on this one were done by a moderator before the count got to 5.

I personally feel like this is fine the way it is. IMO it would be ridiculous for a moderator to *not* be able to close questions, especially with the rash of incomprehensible posts by a certain person we've had lately.

Comment: Hi D M, thanks for your thoughtful explanation. I suspected this was what was going on. Moderators need the ability to close & delete spam posts. However in most cases of closure, as here, it’s much more a matter of judgement and there’s no reason why a moderator’s vote should count more than the vote of any other member in good standing. In my opinion, moderators need the ability to cast “ordinary” close votes, 5 of which would be required to close a question. What do you think?

Comment: And as mentioned in my comment to secret agent man, even an ordinary close vote is excessive and uninformative as an initial response in most non-spam cases. The first response should be a comment expressing one’s concern, and exactly what needs to change. There is always the sanction of making a close vote available later. Posting an unexplained close vote is absolutely toxic behaviour - the default text is insufficient

Comment: I believe the point in closing it is so people don't answer the question if it's about to be significantly modified (which may invalidate the answers.) I think it's fine so long as we do, in fact, promptly reopen it once the edits are made. It's not meant as a punishment for a bad question or something.

Comment: The unexplained pre-emptive closure as usual disrupted the happy answering and it never recovered. Most people just moved on. There is a permanent cloud created by a closure and a lot of time wasted trying to resolve it as the reopening is so difficult. The sanction should be used as a last resort. 

It also presumes that the moderator has perfect judgment in content matters. He or she may be experienced but in these subjective areas they should have the humility to just cast a single vote out of 5 needed rather than destroying the question with a single undocumented click.